# How to send custom struct through CSocket in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to send my custom struct like below:

```
struct Setup
{
int nPort;
BOOL bFirstType;
BOOL bSecondType;
CStringList strPreset1;
CStringList strPreset2;
};
```

But, there's some problem because of `CStringList`

On the receiving side, `CStringList::GetCount()` worked well, but assert error occurred when get string data.

I want to send my data at a time.

So, i tried to convert struct to BYTE and char * but failed.

How i can send struct data at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your data to string form, ie. json or xml, and send it as text, then parse it on the other side and recreate your struct.

Not sure how have you tried converting your struct to BYTE, and how have you failed but above will work if done correctly.

--- [edit] ---

I forgot MFC provides `CArchive` class that together with CMemFile might be usefull with serialization. This solution is actually safe to be used between two MFC applications.

```
struct Setup
{
int nPort;
BOOL bFirstType;
BOOL bSecondType;
CStringList strPreset1;
CStringList strPreset2;
};

int main()
{
  Setup in;
  in.nPort = 81;
  in.bFirstType = TRUE;
  in.bSecondType = FALSE;
  in.strPreset1.AddTail(_T("test1a"));
  in.strPreset1.AddTail(_T("test1b"));
  in.strPreset1.AddTail(_T("test1c"));
  in.strPreset2.AddTail(_T("test2a"));
  in.strPreset2.AddTail(_T("test2b"));
  in.strPreset2.AddTail(_T("test2c"));

  // Serialization part
  CMemFile memfile;
  CArchive ar(&memfile, CArchive::store);

  ar << in.nPort;
  ar << in.bFirstType;
  ar << in.bSecondType;
  in.strPreset1.Serialize(ar);
  in.strPreset2.Serialize(ar);      
  ar.Close();

  INT dataLen = (INT)memfile.GetLength();
  BYTE* data = memfile.Detach();

  // Copy serialized data to some buffer, or to Socket, File, etc.
  std::vector<BYTE> toSent(data, data + dataLen);

  free(data); // after detach and when no longer needed must be freed with free()



  // Now, ie. your second application received your data, so deserialize it.

  CMemFile memfile2;
  memfile2.Attach(&toSent.front(), toSent.size());
  CArchive ar2(&memfile2, CArchive::load);

  Setup out;    
  ar2 >> out.nPort;
  ar2 >> out.bFirstType;
  ar2 >> out.bSecondType;
  out.strPreset1.Serialize(ar2);
  out.strPreset2.Serialize(ar2);
  ar2.Close();


  // Verify if ok, just for testing purposes
  ASSERT(in.nPort == out.nPort);
  ASSERT(in.bFirstType == out.bFirstType);
  ASSERT(in.bSecondType == out.bSecondType);
  ASSERT(in.strPreset1.GetSize() == out.strPreset1.GetSize());
  ASSERT(in.strPreset2.GetSize() == out.strPreset2.GetSize());

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize the struct into a text string/byte/stream (like json, xml, protocol buffer etc), and send them out via CSocket, when you receive the serialized data, deserialize it, then you can handle it.